# trying my hand with recurrent neural networks but I am getting quite a few errors

Tags: javascript, neural-network

At the moment I am having my program run when the mouse is down. But none of the points move. Their positions do not mutate as I want them to. But I cannot find anything wrong with my code. If you would, I would like some second opinions and/or tips/improvements.

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth,windowHeight);
  background(255);
  network = new network();
  for (var i = 0; i < network.populationSize; i++) {
    network.population.push(new object(random(width),random(height)));
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  network.show();
  if (mouseIsPressed) {
    network.generate();
  }
}

function network() {
  this.populationSize = 100;
  this.population = [];
  this.genePool = [];
}

network.prototype.generate = function() {
  this.genePool = [];
  this.genePool = this.population.map(function(curr) {
    curr.mutate();
    curr.calculateFitness();
    curr.genePoolAdd();
    return curr;
  })
  this.population = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < this.populationSize; i++) {
    this.population.push(random(this.genePool));
  }
}

network.prototype.show = function() {
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(5);
  for (var i = 0; i < this.population.length; i++) {
    point(this.population[i].dna[0],this.population[i].dna[1]);
  }
}

function object(x,y) {
  this.dna = [x,y];
  this.mutation = 18;
  this.fitness = this.calculateFitness();
}

object.prototype.mutate = function() {
  for (var i; i < this.dna.length; i++) {
    this.dna[i] += random(-this.mutation,this.mutation);
  }
}

object.prototype.calculateFitness = function() {
  var max = dist(0,0,width/2,height/2);
  return max-dist(this.dna[0],this.dna[1],width/2,height/2);
}

object.prototype.genePoolAdd = function() {
  for(var i = 0; i < pow(this.fitness); i++) {
    genePool.push(new object(this.dna[0],this.dna[1]));
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not making the loop safer by using the array's length as delimitter: `for (var i = 0; i < this.populationSize; i++)` should be `for (var i = 0; i < this.population.length; i++)`!

Comment: I like to use a standard format for my for loops. I would rather use a pre-defined variable than check the length of an array.

Comment: Well the predefined variable causes a problem as you may be accessing elements beyond the length of the array!

Comment: Then that means that my loops are making arrays that are too short! The variable is there to define how long the array should be